# Antd: Multiple addonBefore?

Tags: antd

I'm creating an dashboard for viewing MySQL data. For each field, you can click on the "filter" button to get a popover when you can attach filters. The filters become the `WHERE` statement. Then the data is queried and displayed. It looks like this:

```js
const { Button, Form, Input, Select, Popover } = antd;
const { MinusCircleOutlined, PlusOutlined } = icons;
const { createRoot } = ReactDOM;

let filter_holder = Object();

let fieldsArr = ['duration', 'user_name', 'host_name', 'repo_path', 'build_directory_path', 'platform_name'];

fieldsArr.forEach(name => {
  const elem = document.getElementById(name + '_container');
  if (elem) {
    const App = setupAntdPopoverForm(name);
    createRoot(elem).render(React.createElement(App, null));
  }
});

const prefixOptions = [
    { label: "LIKE", value: "LIKE" },
    { label: "NOT LIKE", value: "NOT LIKE" },
    { label: "=", value: "=" },
    { label: "!=", value: "!=" },
    { label: "BETWEEN", value: "BETWEEN" },
    { label: ">", value: ">" },
    { label: "<", value: "<" },
    { label: ">=", value: ">=" },
    { label: "<=", value: "<=" }
];

const filterForm = (formName) => {
  const onValuesChange = (changedValues, allValues) => {
    filter_holder[formName] = allValues[formName];
    console.log(filter_holder);
    
    let whereArr = new Array();
    Object.keys(filter_holder).forEach((key) => {
        filter_holder[key].forEach((x) =>
            whereArr.push(`(${key} ${x.prefix} '${x.value}')`)
        );
    });
    console.log('WHERE ' + whereArr.join(' AND '));
  }
  return (
    React.createElement(Form, {
        name: "dynamic_form_item_" + formName,
        onValuesChange: onValuesChange,
        style: { maxWidth: 600 },
      },
      React.createElement(Form.List, {
          name: formName,
          initialValue: [{ prefix: 'LIKE' }]
        },
        (fields, { add, remove }, { errors }) => (
          React.createElement(React.Fragment, null,
            fields.map((field) => (
              /* div to hold: input + delete */
              React.createElement("div", {
                  key: field.key,
                  style: {
                    display: "flex",
                    columnGap: 8,
                    marginBottom: 8
                  }
                },
                /* field */
                React.createElement(Form.Item, {
                    name: [field.name, "value"],
                    rules: [{
                      required: true,
                      whitespace: true,
                      message: "Please input a filter or delete this field."
                    }],
                    noStyle: true
                  },
                  React.createElement(Input, {
                    placeholder: "filter",
                    addonBefore: React.createElement(
                      /* prefix field */
                      Form.Item, {
                        name: [field.name, "prefix"],
                        noStyle: true
                      },
                      React.createElement(Select, {
                        popupMatchSelectWidth: false,
                        listHeight: 1000,
                        options: prefixOptions
                      })
                    )
                  })
                ),
                /* Remove item button */
                React.createElement(MinusCircleOutlined, {
                  onClick: () => remove(field.name)
                })
              )
            )),
            /* "add field" button */
            React.createElement(Form.Item, null,
              React.createElement(Button, {
                onClick: () => add({ prefix: "LIKE" }),
                icon: React.createElement(PlusOutlined, null)
              }, "add field"),
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  );
};

function setupAntdPopoverForm(name) {
  const App = () => (
    React.createElement(Popover, {
        title: name,
        content: filterForm(name),
        trigger: "click"
      },
      React.createElement(Button, null, "filter"))
  );
  return App;
}
```

```css
table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>duration</th>
            <th>user</th>
            <th>host</th>
            <th>repo path</th>
            <th>build directory</th>
            <th>platform</th>
        </tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div id="duration_container"></td>
            <td><div id="user_name_container"></td>
            <td><div id="host_name_container"></td>
            <td><div id="repo_path_container"></td>
            <td><div id="build_directory_path_container"></td>
            <td><div id="platform_name_container"></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script src='https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js'></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js'></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/dayjs@1/dayjs.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/antd@5.11.5/dist/antd-with-locales.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/@ant-design/icons/dist/index.umd.js'></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom/dist/umd/react-router-dom.production.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/react-router/dist/umd/react-router.production.min.js'></script>
<script src="./script.js"></script>
```

I would like to add a second `addonBefore` type field, before the first, that allows the user to toggle between `AND` and `OR`.

It seems like Antd only allows one `addonBefore`. Is there any way around that? Or some other way of creating something that looks/functions like that?

I can't use `addonAfter`. The order matters: it needs to go:

> `[AND/OR]` `[prefixOptions]` `[typing field]`